# I am getting all of th links but I am just wanting the registration links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    import pandas as pd

    sca_url = "https://steakcookoffs.com/cookoffs?EventViewMode=1&EventListViewMode=1"
    client = uReq(sca_url)
    page_html = client.read()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, features='lxml')

    sca_reg_links_tags = page_soup.select(".inner a")

    print(sca_reg_links_tags)
```

How can i just get the registration link??
I've also tried using sca_reg_links_tags = page_soup.find('div', {"class":"inner"})
but it would obtain the same thing.

Comment: There are about a hundred registration links on that page.  Which one do you want?

Comment: i just need to know how to obtain one and then ill set up loop to store all of them.

Comment: You mean the registration link for each of the events listed, right? So, first one would be: https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4692176/Registration. Correct?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the baroquely complicated code on this page?  (100,000 lines of Javascript????)  It looks like the register links are all in `<a>` tags with no classes.  You will have to fetch ALL of the `<a>` tags, and look for those that have "Register" as their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
soup.find_all("a", string="Register")
```

Also, bs4 documentation:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
sca_reg_links_tags = page_soup.find_all('a', {'title': 'View event details'})

lst = []
for link in sca_reg_links_tags:
    lst.append(link['href']+'/Registration')

lst[:5]

['https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4572070/Registration',
 'https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4572070/Registration',
 'https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4692176/Registration',
 'https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4692176/Registration',
 'https://steakcookoffs.com/event-4901583/Registration']
```

Happy cooking!